# Estou tendo dúvidas em como utilizar as chaves "{"

Tags: c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class MOVIMENTO : MonoBehaviour
{
private float spd = 0.9f;
private GameObject camera;
private GameObject gameOverUI;
public bool gameOver;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
camera = GameObject.Find("Camera");
gameOver = false;
gameOverUI = GameObject.Find("GAME OVER");
gameOverUI.gameObject.active - false;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
if (gameOver == false) {
//camera.transform.position = transform.position - new Vector3(-12f ,-3 ,0 );
//if (Input.GetKey("w"))
transform.position += new Vector3(-spd ,0 ,0 );

if (Input.GetKey("d"))
transform.position += new Vector3(0 ,0 ,spd );
//if (Input.GetKey("space"))
//transform.position += new Vector3(0 ,2 ,0 );

if (Input.GetKey("a"))
transform.position += new Vector3(0 ,0 ,-spd );

//if (Input.GetKey("space"))
//transform.position += new Vector3(0 ,2 ,0 );
//NITRO
//if (Input.GetKey("c"))
//transform.position += new Vector3(-1 ,0 ,0 );

if (Input.GetKey("e"))
Debug.Log("PRESTOU!");

public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision obj){
if (obj.gameObject.tag == "POLICIAL BOSTA") {
gameOverUI = gameObject.active = true;
gameOver = true;
Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
Debug.Log("JAERA!");


if (obj.gameObject.tag == "Caio") {
transform.position += new Vector3(0 ,2 ,0 );

//if (obj.gameObject.tag == "Vitor") {
//transform.position += new Vector3(-4 ,0 ,0 );
//}
//if (obj.gameObject.tag == "Arta") {
//transform.position += new Vector3(0 ,2 ,0 );
//}
if (obj.gameObject.tag == "Fim da linha") {
Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);

if (obj.gameObject.tag == "NITRO") {
transform.position += new Vector3(-9 ,0 ,0 );
}
}
}
```

eu estou tentando fazer um jogo na unity, so q ta dando erro de abrir e fechar chaves "{}" ai n da pra executar o jogo por causa disso,ai no console do unity fala assim:

> Assets\MOVIMENTO.cs(46,5): error CS0106: The modifier 'public' is not
>   valid for this item

oq eu faço pra resolver?

Comment: Comece a endentar o seu código.

Comment: Depois do `Debug.Log("JAERA!");` falta uma `}`

Answer (score 1):

Eu indentei o seu código e removi chaves que você **abriu** mas não **fechou** e foi por isso que deu origem a um **erro maior** que foi a função '*OnColisionEnter*' não ter chave para **fechar**!

Comece a fazer **indentação** nos seus códigos, isso ajuda na **organização** e na **legibilidade** do código!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class MOVIMENTO : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float spd = 0.9f;
    private GameObject camera;
    private GameObject gameOverUI;
    public bool gameOver;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        camera = GameObject.Find("Camera");
        gameOver = false;
        gameOverUI = GameObject.Find("GAME OVER");
        gameOverUI.gameObject.active - false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (gameOver == false) 
            //camera.transform.position = transform.position - new Vector3(-12f ,-3 ,0 );
            //if (Input.GetKey("w"))
            transform.position += new Vector3(-spd ,0 ,0 );

        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
            transform.position += new Vector3(0 ,0 ,spd );
            //if (Input.GetKey("space"))
            //transform.position += new Vector3(0 ,2 ,0 );

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
            transform.position += new Vector3(0 ,0 ,-spd );

        //if (Input.GetKey("space"))
            //transform.position += new Vector3(0 ,2 ,0 );
            //NITRO
        //if (Input.GetKey("c"))
            //transform.position += new Vector3(-1 ,0 ,0 );

        if (Input.GetKey("e"))
            Debug.Log("PRESTOU!");
    }

    public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision obj){
        if (obj.gameObject.tag == "POLICIAL BOSTA"){
            gameOverUI = gameObject.active = true;
            gameOver = true;
            Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
            Debug.Log("JAERA!");
        }

        if (obj.gameObject.tag == "Caio") 
            transform.position += new Vector3(0 ,2 ,0 );

        //if (obj.gameObject.tag == "Vitor")
            //transform.position += new Vector3(-4 ,0 ,0 );

        //if (obj.gameObject.tag == "Arta")
            //transform.position += new Vector3(0 ,2 ,0 );

        if (obj.gameObject.tag == "Fim da linha")
            Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);

        if (obj.gameObject.tag == "NITRO")
            transform.position += new Vector3(-9 ,0 ,0 );
    }
}
```